# Is there any relation between the two Captains Scott?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Of course, I referring to [Chief Engineer/Captain Montgomery Scott](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Montgomery_Scott) and [Captain Tryla Scott](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tryla_Scott), "*one of Starfleet's fines*t" from [TNG: Conspiracy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Conspiracy_(episode))

[image] [image]

Has any canon or (more likely) Expanded Universe source suggested a familial link between them?

Comment: Dunno. Don't think so. There have also been other Scotts in the show including an engineer on the Franklin and a MACO on the Enterprise; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Scott

Comment: @Valorum:   Then let's throw them in the mix too!   I also think not, but on the other hand, it wouldn't shock me if some novel somewhere dreamt up a relation.

Comment: Some folks have postulated a relationship-of-convenience between Scotty and Uhura so..................

Comment: The resemblance is clear!

Answer (score 1):

### Main canon

**There's no indication in any of the films, TV shows or other media that she's related to the Montgomery Scott.**

It's a relatively common name [within the franchise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scott_(disambiguation)) as well as in reality. Additionally, her [profile page on StarTrek.com](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/scott-t) makes no reference to any famous ancestors.

### EU Canon

Kirk and Picard briefly meet up in the EU Novel [Star Trek: Preserver](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Preserver_(novel)). Tryla Scott is mentioned. **Kirk doesn't know who she is, nor is any mention made of her relative being someone that Kirk knows intimately.**

> “Focusing only on Starfleet command appointments made in the past twenty years,” Savrin answered, “we have identified thirty seven orders generated with a lack of traceable authorization codes.”
>
> **“Are you familiar with Captain Tryla Scott?” Picard asked Kirk.**
>
> **Kirk wasn’t.**
>
> “She broke your record for youngest starship captain. Her orders can’t be traced.”

Comment: Agreed! It’d be a name coincidence just like there are millions of “Smith” family names.